# Why does Java allow arrays of size 0?

Tags: java, arrays

Arrays in java are fixed in length. Why does Java allow arrays of size 0 then?

```
String[] strings = new String[0];
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

It signifies that it is empty. I.e. you can loop over it as if it had items and have no result occur:

```
for(int k = 0; k < strings.length; k++){
   // something
}
```

Thereby avoiding the need to check. If the array in question were `null`, an exception would occur, but in this case it just does nothing, which may be appropriate.

Comment: It is also useful for calling a function `test(Object... objects)` explicit when there is a function `test()`

Answer (score 54):

Why does Java allow arrays of size 1? Isn't it pretty useless to wrap a single value in an array? Wouldn't it be sufficient if Java only allowed arrays of size 2 or greater?

Yes, we can pass `null` instead of an empty array and a single object or primitive instead of a size-one-matrix.

But there are some good arguments against such an restriction. My personal top arguments:

**Restriction is too complicated and not really necessary**

To limit arrays to sizes [1..INTEGER.MAX_INT] we'd have to add <strike>a lot of additional boudary checks,</strike>*(agree to Konrads comment)* conversion logic and method overloads to our code. Excluding 0 (and maybe 1) from the allowed array sizes does not save costs, it requires additional effort and has an negative impact on performance.

**Array models vector**

An array is a good data model for a vector (mathematics, *not* the `Vector` class!). And of course, a vector in mathematics may be zero dimensional. Which is conceptually different from being non-existant.

---

**Sidenote** - a prominent wrapper for an (char-)array is the `String` class. The immutable `String` materializes the concept of an empty array: it is the empty String (`""`).

Comment: I don’t believe your restriction argument. Java (unlike e.g. C) already requires a check for negative numbers. This check could trivially be adapted to accomodate 0 (just change `>= 0` to `> 0`). But you’re of course right about the rest so adding this restriction wouldn’t be meaningful.

Comment: The loop iteration argument seems better in my opinion: "for(int k = 0; k < strings.length; k++){
   // something
}"

Comment: No, it is not to *my* opinion, because in a world without zero-size arrays, empty strings (based on char arrays) simply wouldn't exist and so there wouldn't be any need to consider empty arrays in loops. This iteration argument is a very practical side effect. In that world, an array would have one entry at minimum. (Or two because: why would one need an array for just one item?)

Comment: The check for a negative index and a too high index are the same check: negative indexes are always unsigned-not-less-than the length of the array

Answer (score 29):

Sometimes it's much more friendly to return a zero size array than null.

Comment: This is called the "Null Object" pattern.

Answer (score 18):

Consider this (a more detailed explanation of Noon's answer):

```
public String[] getStrings() {
 if( foo ) {
  return null;
 } else {
  return new String[] {"bar, "baz"};
 }
}

String[] strings = getStrings();
if (strings != null) {
 for (String s : strings) {
  blah(s);
 }
}
```

Now compare it to this:

```
public String[] getStrings() {
 if( foo ) {
  return new String[0];
 } else {
  return new String[] {"bar, "baz"};
 }
}

// the if block is not necessary anymore
String[] strings = getStrings();
for (String s : strings) {
 blah(s);
}
```

This (returning empty arrays rather than null values), is in fact a best practice in Java API design world.

Besides, in Java, you can covert Lists (e.g. ArrayList) to arrays and it only makes sense to convert an empty list to an empty array.

Answer (score 7):

Another case where a zero length array can be useful:
To return an array containing all of the elements in a list :

```
<T> T[ ] toArray(T[ ] a)
```

A zero length array can be used to pass the type of the array into this method. For example:

```
ClassA[ ] result = list.toArray(new ClassA[0]);
```

A zero length array is still an instance of Object which holds zero elements.

Answer (score 6):

Same as C++, it allows for cleaner handling when there is no data.

Answer (score 2):

A 0-length `byte[]`, or `char[]` can represent an empty `String`, which is distinct from `null`. Getting the bytes, or characters, as arrays from strings (using `getBytes()`, `getChars()` of `String` class etc.) and the vice-versa of forming `String`s from `byte[]`, `char[]` is quite common. For example, for custom encoding, decoding of strings.

Comment: They use 0-sized arrays, because it's useful. It's not useful, because they use 0-sized arrays.

Answer (score 1):

One case I can think of where an empty array is extremely useful is to use it instead of null in a situation where null isn't allowed. One possible example of that is a BlockingQueue of arrays. When you want to signal the end of input to the reading side, what would you do? To send null seems like an obvious choice, but the thing is that BlockingQueue doesn't accept nulls. You could wrap your array inside a class with "`boolean last;`" kind of field, but that's kind of overkill. Sending an empty (zero-sized) array seems like the most reasonable choice.

Answer (score 1):

Another case when a zero length array is useful is when copying a two dimensional array. I can write:

```
public int[][] copyArray(int[][] array){
     int[][] newArray = new int[array.length][0];
     for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
         newArray[i] = array[i];
     }
     return newArray;
```

Being that every array reference in array is being overwritten, initializing them as refernces to zero length arrays is most efficient.

Comment: This is quite misleading code. If someone has a 2-d int array `a` and says `b = copyArray(a);`, changing the data pointed to by `a` will change the data pointed to by `b`. That doesn't sound like a copy to me.