# check if 2d array is valid

Tags: java, arrays

assume someMethodThatCenReturnZero() returns 0:

```
int[][] scanArray = new int[someMethodThatCenReturnZero()][2];

if (scanArray == null) {
  PApplet.println("null");
}

if (scanArray[0] == null) {
    PApplet.println("null");
}
```

it won't print null, but i get a index out of bound exception.

I could catch it with a try block. Also i could check for `someMethodThatCenReturnZero() > 0` before creating the array. But for the purpose of learning, is there another way?

Comment: `if(scanArray.length > 0)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanArray.length` will give `zero` if `someMethodThatCenReturnZero()` returns `zero`. So your condition could be :

```
if(scanArray.length == 0){
  PApplet.println("null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program won't print `null` because you instantiated `scanArray` with the `new` operator. You can try `if(scanArray.length > 0)` to attain the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

If this line completes successfully:

```
int[][] scanArray = new int[someMethodThatCenReturnZero()][2];
```

Then this can never happen:

```
if (scanArray == null) {
   PApplet.println("null");
}
```

The result of calling `new` will never be null. Instead you should check `scanArray.length == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You made `scanArray` not `null` when you called `new int[someMethodThatCenReturnZero()][2]`

You are receiving an index out of bounds because if `someMethodThatCenReturnZero` returns `0` the array has a size of `0` and you are trying to access the first item `scanArray[0]` which is out of the bounds of the array.

When an `array` is indexed `0` to `(size of the array) - 1`, or in the case of a `0` size `array` has no valid indices.

Best practice in `Java` is to check the `length` property of the array before assuming there is a 0<sup>th</sup> element.

```
if (scanArray.length > 0) {
    System.out.println("Non empty!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Empty!");
}
```

If you want to check if any of the array elements are null:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scanArray.length; i++) {
    if (scanArray[i] == null) {
        System.out.println("The " + i + "th element is null");
    }
}
```

This loop allows for *safe* calling of any index because in the case that it is empty the `for` loop is given the instruction to only run through the loop when `i < scanArray.length`.  `i` is initiated to `0` so when the `length` is `0` the `for` loop never runs.

The last code snippet is a commonly used way of handling a *possibly-empty-array* as it is a loop which loops only over valid indices of the `array`.

Your original approac follows a style coined commonly in the python world as EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission), i.e. you just go for it and deal with exceptions if they come up.

The `for` loop approach or `length` check follows the LBYL (Look Before You Leap) methodology which takes neccessary steps to avoid situations where an `Exception` could be thrown (i.e. `null` checking as you had in your example for `scanArray == null`).

Since `Java` is a very explicit language the LBYL style of coding is generally preferred, but both are valid, one is just more hap hazard (EAFP).  [This discussion is worth looking at.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404795/lbyl-vs-eafp-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [array of length zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612471/why-does-java-allow-arrays-of-size-0), but that array is literally you expect it to be: an array of length zero.

An array of length 0 is not `null`.

By trying to access `scanArray[0]` you're trying to accessing the first element of the array, but the array does not have any elements.