# Can't add integer to an array without a 0 at first index

Tags: java, arrays, addition

I used an `ArrayList` at first. But then my course teacher told me that I can't use `ArrayList` in my program. He said that I can only use arrays.

The problem is when I add an integer to array, it just puts zero on the first index.

Here is the code :

```
int[] Bag = new int[1];
boolean isit = true;
do {
    int[] NewBag = new int[Bag.length + 1]; 
    String name = scanner.next();

    if (name.equals("A")){
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < Bag.length; i++) {
            NewBag[NewBag.length - 1] = number;
            NewBag[i] = Bag[i];
        }
        Bag = NewBag;
        System.out.println(number + " added to Bag.");
    }
} while (isit == true);
```

Please help me guys. I can't make Minimum and Size operations without the correct Add operation.

Comment: `int[] NewBag = new int[Bag.length + 1];` Why is this inside the loop? You're creating a new instance on each iteration.

Comment: It just make things worse. If i take that out of "do" loop, array only stores last input. Deleting first ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start with a single-element array, and immediately add a second element to it:

```
    int[] NewBag = new int[Bag.length + 1];
```

Thus by the time you've read one number your array already contains two elements (i.e. one element too many).

To correct this, you need to change the

```
    int[] Bag = new int[1];
```

to

```
    int[] Bag = new int[0];
```

If this looks odd, see [Why does Java allow arrays of size 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612471/why-does-java-allow-arrays-of-size-0)

You'll also need to move

```
NewBag[NewBag.length - 1] = number;
```

out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But when i change it to 0, if i input 5,6,7,8 it stores 0,6,7,8.

Comment: @user3613007: Move `NewBag[NewBag.length - 1] = number;` out of the loop.

Comment: Yes, it works correctly now. Thank you a lot for responding fast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do with your array, but if you want to wrap an array into something, that has similar methods to an ArrayList, you could do something like this (mind, that once it reaches the array's size, int wont grow.):

```
class MyArray {
    private final int[] mArray;
    private int mSize = 0;

    public MyArray(final int maxSize) {
        mArray = new int[maxSize];
    }

    public void add(final int element) {
        if (mSize < mArray.length) {
            mArray[mSize++] = element;
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("No more room");
        }
    }

    public int get(final int index) {
        return mArray[index];
    }

    public int size() {
        return mSize;
    }
}
```

Then you could do your logic:

```
int maxSize = scanner.nextInt();
MyArray array = new MyArray(maxSize);

for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++) {
   array.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```