# How to call a method that uses potentially uninitilized arrays as paramaters?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, methods, parameters

I'm writing a program that reads a text file into parallel arrays, then allows users to request that entries that match criteria be printed to a separate file. I declare these arrays at the beginning of the code, but do not initialize them until later as their length relies on data extracted from the file.

I'm now trying to write the methods that print the filtered results to a file, but eclipse is telling me I can't pass them as parameters because they aren't initialized. But they are initialized, just within a loop. I can't initialize them earlier, because the program won't know the required length yet.

Relevant bits of code

```
            filterLocation(time, longitude, magnitude, latitude, location, description, entries);
```

where the errors are, when I try to call the method from the main method

```
public static void filterLocation (String[] time, 
                                    double[] latitude,
                                    double[] longitude,
                                    double[] magnitude,
                                    String[] location,
                                    String[] description,
                                    int entries )
```

The method I'm trying to write, where no errors are detected by eclipse.

```
    String[] time;
    double[] latitude;
    double[] longitude;
    double[] magnitude;
    String[] location;
    String[] description;
```

where the variables are declared, right under public static void main...

```
if(entries!=0){
                    time = new String[entries];
                    latitude = new double[entries];
                    longitude = new double[entries];
                    magnitude = new double[entries];
                    location = new String[entries];
                    description = new String[entries];
```

where they are initialized, nested in a while loop, if statement and try block

Comment: We need to see more code. Show us how the variables are declared and subsequently initialized.

Comment: you can use `ArrayList` instead of `array`

Comment: Updated. ArrayLists are not an option for this question.

Comment: in that case you can call your method in your `if` condition where they are initialized .

Comment: Also not an option because the method needs to be called from within a separate if statement. Looks like what I'm trying to do here simply isn't possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the variables in the method from which filterLocation is called. Seems like you are not initializing the variable there.

**EDIT**:

There is a condition in your code

```
 if(entries!=0){
```

which prevents the initialization. The compiler is pointing out the condition What if the entries = 0 ? That condition is not met.

You should met that condition too for avoiding compilation error.

See a dummy code below.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int a;
    if (args != null) {
        a = 10;
    } else {
        a = 11;
    }
    sampleMethod(a);

}

public static void sampleMethod(int a) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Remove the else condition, and see the compilation error.

Hope you understand the problem.

**EDIT**

Or Call the method inside the condition itself. See dummy code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a;
    if (args != null) {
        a = 10;
        sampleMethod(a);
    }

}

public static void sampleMethod(int a) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

**EDIT**

Or the variable should be at class level.

```
public class TestMethod {
private int a;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestMethod method = new TestMethod();
    method.wrapperMethod(args);

}

public void wrapperMethod(String[] args) {
    if (args != null) {
        a = 10;
    }
    sampleMethod(a);
}

public static void sampleMethod(int a) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Quoting from [java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> Each method parameter (§8.4.1) is initialized to the corresponding
>   argument value provided by the invoker of the method (§15.12).
>
> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
>   before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
>   (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite
>   assignment (§16).

Comment: They are initialized, however they are initialized nested in several blocks as is necessary for their initialization.

Comment: But that condition is a requirement for them to be initialized in the first place. The program is designed so the method filterLocation can only be called if the arrays have been initialized, but Java doesn't seem to care.

Comment: I see what you mean, unfortunately that's not an option based on how the assignment is structured. We are specifically instructed to pass the arrays in this way, so I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Actually it is in java spec. See last point in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5 But you can do it if those variables are class members.. See the edit

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that last point, it seems to refer to issues with conflicting classes or something beyond me

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have to rewrite most of the program but I guess that's better than it not working at all.

Comment: You are welcome Spork. I have also quoted the java spec too. Thanks for accepting

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `if` condition:

```
if(entries!=0){
```

If `entries` is zero, you never initialize the arrays. This is what the compiler is complaining about.

The easiest fix is to just remove the `if` while keeping the initializations:

```
                time = new String[entries];
                latitude = new double[entries];
                ...
```

Allocating zero-size arrays is perfectly fine in Java. For a discussion, see [Why does Java allow arrays of size 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612471/why-does-java-allow-arrays-of-size-0)

To make the code more compact, you can even merge the declaration with initialization:

```
String[] time = new String[entries];
double[] latitude = new double[entries];
...
```

Comment: I understand that now, unfortunately the way the program is structured it isn't possible to just remove that if block, as if the file has 0 entries the arrays should not be initialized and instead the user should be thrown back to the menu and told to retry with a valid file.