# String[] names = String[0]; is this valid?

Tags: java, arrays

I tested on [this website](https://quizlet.com/10055992/java-quiz-5-arrays-flash-cards/):

```
String[] names =new String[0];
```

The result says this is valid, but when I test it on IDE, I get an error. Someone tell me why?

Comment: Which website telling `String[] names = String[0];`  this is right way to declare `String` object? Please let us know we will take tuition from them

Comment: Nothing Wrong to declare like this `String[] names = new String[0];` What exception or compile time error you are getting?

Comment: The **number one** rule on StackOverflow: Don't tell us "I get an error" without telling us what the error is.  Why why why why why why why why why do questioners feel they have to keep secrets from us?????????????????????????

Comment: So are you still getting an error after adding the `new`?  If you are, please tell us what it is.  If you're not, then don't leave the question up.  Close it.

Comment: @ajb: sorry you, i will note this

Comment: @QuanNguyen: There's no use in doing this. You are declaring an array of Strings, which can contain: 0 Strings.

Comment: @Stultuske: Arrays is immutable size, so if you declare String[] names = new String[0], bebauce size never change, then i think it  can not use.

Comment: @QuanNguyen that was indeed my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] names = new String[0];
```

is a valid statement (as [the web-quiz that you mention](https://quizlet.com/10055992/java-quiz-5-arrays-flash-cards/) suggests), even if I question its usability, since it creates an array of zero length, so you cannot add any elements to it...

The error that you imply (I think) in your comment

> *"If creating an array of type String and size 0. I think names variable is not used. we can not assign a value to names variable. thanks"*

in [Amit Bhati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31957078/2516301)'s (perfectly valid) answer, is not an error.

"Variable not used" is a *warning*, telling you that you declare something that you never use. In other words, you do not assign any values to this array. The warning will be gone, if you actually use the `names` variable afterwards and assign a value to it (even if it makes no sense, since it has 0 length).

For example:

```
names[0] = "something";
```

This will turn the IDE warning into a runtime problem, though...

EDIT: As for WHY java allows the declaration of a 0-length array, you can follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612471/why-does-java-allow-arrays-of-size-0).

Comment: Why not  IDE  issue a error when we declare a array on which never use. String[] names = new String[0];// never, never use

Comment: @QuanNguyen that's a different (good) question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612471/why-does-java-allow-arrays-of-size-0)

Answer (score 7):

`String[] names` can be initialized in many ways:

```
(1) String[] names = {};
(2) String[] names = new String[0];
(3) String[] names = new String[] {};
```

Answer (score 5):

You missed new operator:-

```
String[] names =new String[0];
```

But you need to give some size to the array in order to use it.
Above code is creating an array of type String and size 0.

Comment: If  creating an array of type String and size 0. I think names variable is not used. we can not assign a value to names variable. thanks