# LinkedList Matrix, Null Pointer Exception when setting value

Tags: java, matrix, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I started with a 2D array matrix program that works entirely ok. I converted most of it to implement a linked list version of the same thing. Currently (using .printStackTrace) I find my null pointer exception is from this line -> matrix.setValue(matrixRow, matrixColumn, value);

which calls setValue and the error is thrown at this -> a[x][y] = value;    //error in this line

I hope to have included enough code, let me know if more info is helpful. In need of a coding break for the moment. Many thanks.

```
else {      //matrix creation
                    matrix = new Node();
                    int matrixRow = 1;
                    int matrixColumn = 1;

                    for (int i = 1; i <= matrixSize; i++) {
                        //scanner one line at a time
                        scanner = new Scanner(fileIO.getNextLine());
                        if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                            while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                                value = scanner.nextDouble();
                                matrix.construct(matrixRow, matrixColumn);
                                matrix.setValue(matrixRow, matrixColumn, value);
                                matrixColumn++;
                            }//while
                            matrixRow++;
                            matrixColumn = 1;
                        }//if
                    }//for
                    if (matrix.isSquare()) {
                        determinant = matrixMaths.determinate(matrix);
                        fileIO.writeToOutput(matrix.toString());
                        fileIO.writeToOutput("The determinant is: " + String.valueOf(determinant));
                        fileIO.writeToOutput("\n\n");
                    } else {
                        errorMsg = "\n\nMatrix is not square.\n\n";
                        fileIO.writeToOutput(errorMsg);
                    }//else
                }//else matrix creation

Node construct(int n, int m) {
Node[][] a = new Node[n][m];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        Node ptr = new Node();
        ptr.data = a[i][j];
        ptr.right = null;
        ptr.down = null;
        a[i][j] = ptr;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (j != n - 1)
            a[i][j].right = a[i][j + 1];
        if (i != n - 1)
            a[i][j].down = a[i + 1][j];
    }
}
return a[0][0];
}

public void setValue(int x, int y, double value) {
a[x][y] = value;    //error in this line
if (x > sizeX) {
    sizeX = x;
}
if (y > sizeY) {
    sizeY = y;
}
}
```

*** Edit ***
I had put in system.out statements right before I called setValue to see that I was passing the values of 1 to the array. The method only gets this far until I get the error.
So, setValue(matrixRow, matrixColumn, value) -> setValue(1,1,value); on the first go through the while loop. I changed to this

```
int matrixRow = 0;
int matrixColumn = 0;
```

but then get the new error here (last return in the construct method):

```
 return a[0][0];
```

another arrayOutOfBounds...
I'm going to try to follow the logic again but not sure yet where to make the fix. Help please!
And changing the row/column = 2 also gets the NUllPtr again.

So, made a few changes and am getting further...

```
} else {      //matrix creation
    matrix = new Node();
    int matrixRow = 0;
    int matrixColumn = 0;
    System.out.println("\n" +  "matrixSize " + matrixSize);
    for (int i = 1; i <= matrixSize; i++) {
        //scanner one line at a time
        scanner = new Scanner(fileIO.getNextLine());
        if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            while (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            value = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(matrixRow + " row number");
            System.out.println(matrixColumn + " column number");
            System.out.println(value + " value");
            matrix.construct(matrixRow, matrixColumn, value);
            matrixColumn++;
 }//while
            matrixRow++;
            matrixColumn = 1;
 }
```

My input is this...

```
3
3 -2 4 
-1 5 2 
-3 6 4
```

Output gets through matrices size 1 and 2. It gets as far as the third matrix row 3, column 0. At row 3, col 0, I get the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error again.

I had it working but then ran into trouble setting the values but....  the project is to be a "matrix as a linked list" which is different than the previous assignment "matrix as a 2D array". So perhaps my structures are incorrect to begin with? Also, My Node class is separate (as an ADT implementing an interface). There is a whole 'nother class for finding the determinant. Not worried about that at right now. Also, we are given the "matrix size" the line before the matrix data in the input. And thank you again!

**Can't sleep edit...
This construct works through the entire input file. So now I just need to figure out where to set the values. (Value is not being assigned here so I'll likely delete it unless I can figure out a way around that).

```
void construct(int n, int m, double value) {
    System.out.println("construct " + n + " n " + m + " m " + value + " value");
    Node[][] a = new Node[n + 1][m + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            Node ptr = new Node();
            ptr.data = a[i][j];
            ptr.right = null;
            ptr.down = null;
            a[i][j] = ptr;
            a[i][j].right = a[i][j + 1];
            a[i][j].down = a[i + 1][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your previous code working with the arrays? The array is the most primitive **collection** you can imagine! And... You moved the code to some higher level, **and** it doesn't work? I'm really sorry...

Comment: @zlakad....do you have any suggestions on getting it to work? These are homework labs and I've had immense struggles with the entire class. My java was lacking, better now than 3 months ago but for the life of me... I don't know. I have a nagging feeling it has to do with the Linked list construction. Node construct().

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an off by one error. If we replace the values:

```
int matrixRow = 1;
int matrixColumn = 1;
```

into what is being declared, we see that you are accessing the array at the place `a[1][1]`, but your declaration for the array size is `Node[][] a = new Node[1][1];` (when replacing n and m by the value above). This means that the only element accessible for setValue is `a[0][0]` (because arrays have a length of `size - 1`.

I suggest you do an array bounds-checking if-statement on the setValue function, you'll be able to catch errors like this with greater ease. Another way to check my theory is to set matrixRow and matrixColumn as 2 and insert a debug print statement for the array at the beginning of the setValue function, and see what is the first element populated.

---

Edit:
The reason you get an error in your construct function is because you are creating a zero length array, and then trying to access its first element (see [Why does Java allow arrays of size 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612471/why-does-java-allow-arrays-of-size-0) for more info on zero length arrays in java)

I don't know the nature of your project, but I suggest you separate the logic of your code. It seems that you are representing your matrix as an array of "`Node`"s, and that you know the size of the matrix beforehand. 
If so, I would suggest representing your matrix as a class, and making the construct method return and instance of that class.

At the very least, I see no reason as to why you should need to create the matrix inside the while loop. Create it beforehand, and populate it with values later.