# Why is declaring an empty array of non-empty array(s) legal in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Curious why declaring an empty array of non-emtpy array(s) is legal in Java:

```
int[][] array = new int[0][1];

System.out.println(array[][0]); //won't compile.
System.out.println(array[0][0]) //triggers an out of bounds exception.
```

P.S. I have read the related question on zero-size arrays: [Why does Java allow arrays of size 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612471/why-does-java-allow-arrays-of-size-0)

Is this for the same reason?

Comment: `array[0]` is a reference to the _first_ element of `array`; that element does not exist. That is why you have the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is legal to define empty arrays in general, no matter what it contains. Thus, it is also legal to have an empty array containing non empty arrays.

Mathematically (group theory) speaking, empty arrays are not only legal, but necessary, since they represent the zero (or neutral) element of array concatenation operation. This also makes it useful for programming (see the example below).

In your example you basically probe, if it is ok to access elements of an empty array. This is of course not legal, since there are none. However you can do:

```
int[][] array = new int[0][1];
System.out.println(array.length);
```

With reference to my own example above, a more useful case is:

```
    int[][] array1 = new int[1][1];
    int[][] array2 = new int[0][1];

    array1[0][0] = 1;

    int [][] concat = Stream
            .concat(Arrays.stream(array1), Arrays.stream(array2))
            .toArray(int[][]::new);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(concat));
```

Thus empty arrays allow to for "good" code, without `if`s to exclude, illegal cases, which actually are totally fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for quoting the theoretical background and pointing to the use of Stream interface for uniform treatment of empty and non-empty arrays. Had to take time reading the Stream functionality thoroughly

Answer (score 2):

An `int[][]` array is an array whose elements are `int[]` (i.e. its elements are arrays of `int`).

Just like you are allowed to define an empty array of `int` elements:

```
int[] empty = new int[0];
```

or an empty array of `String` elements:

```
String[] empty = new String[0];
```

You are also allowed to define an empty array of `int[1]` elements:

```
int[][] empty = new int[0][1];
```

Perhaps it's the syntax that is somewhat confusing here.

If it was

```
int[][] empty = new (int[1])[0]
```

it would be clearer that you are defining an empty array whose element type is `int[1]`.

However, since the number in the first square brackets represents the number of elements in the outer array, `new int[1][0]` does not represent an empty array, but an array of a single element (whose single element is an empty `int` array).

Answer (score 0):

An array dimension of zero means the array has zero elements. Hence there is no element at index 0 (zero).

When you declare a two-dimensional array in Java, the first array dimension is mandatory.

Refer to [chapter 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) of the *Java Language Specification*.

Answer (score 0):

as per your declaration:

`int[][] array = new int[0][1];`

you have declared 2D array where length of the array is `0`
it means it will not be able to contain any element thats why

`System.out.println(array[0][0])`. array[0][0] is out of bound index error